# not able to download FTP file to local directory java

Tags: java, ftp, download

If I try to download file like like below it is getting downloaded here

```
client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, fos);  // working
```

But if i try to to download FTP file to particular local directory as below it is not getting downloaded there. Can anybody tell me why this is happening ?

```
client.retrieveFile("C:\MydownloadedFiles" + filename, fos); // not working
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is "client"? Without knowing what FTP library you're using it's going to be very difficult for anyone to give advice on what may be wrong.

Comment: Wild guess: a `\ ` is missing in the second retrieve (also note that you need to escape `\ `s)

Answer (score 1):

Please escape the "\". 
It should be:

```
client.retrieveFile("C:\\MydownloadedFiles" + "\\" + filename, fos);
```

In general I would recommend working with the constant File.separator, to support cross-platform. 
Another idea I have in mind (please test it) is the following:

```
File downloadsDirectory = new File("c:","MyDownloadedFiles");
File retrievedFileOnLocalComp = new File(downloadsDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),filename);
client.retrieveFile(retrievedFileOnComp.getAbsolutePath(),fos);
```

Explanation- 
The first line creates a download directory under the parent path of "c:" 
The second line creates the file name to download to with parent directory equals to the absolute path of the result from the first line. 
The third downloads to it.
You had an issue with rememembering to use "\\".
I suggest to use these three lines in order to solve this issue and to get rid of platform dependant decision on the slash-type.

Comment: client is FTPClient client = new FTPClient();                         I tried client.retrieveFile("C:\\MydownloadedFiles" + filename, fos);  but still it is not copying in that folder.

Comment: @user1833019 - if it worked, I would appreciate you mark this as the correct answer